# Radio Buttons stopped working when styled as button look like

Tags: html, css

I have a problem I have styled my radio buttons. After style, these radio buttons stop working.
I styled them as actual button looked like.
Please let me know if there is any problem with the HTML or CSS. Many thanks in advance.

<[Check Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mk02hsnt/2/)>

```css
  .radio-toolbar {
  margin: 10px;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
   width: 0;
   position: absolute;
  
}

.radio-toolbar span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 30.33%;
    margin:5px 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.radio-toolbar span:hover {
  background-color:#f79da9;
  color:#fff;
  transition:0.5s;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:focus + span {
    border: 2px dashed #444;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
    background-color: #bfb;
    border-color: #4c4;
}
```

```html
<body>
                     <label>Time Zone: EST</label>
                  <p class="line-item-property__field radio-toolbar">
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="10:00 am" checked><span>10:00 am</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="11:00 am"> <span>11:00 am</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="12:00 am"><span>12:00 am</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="1:00 pm"> <span>1:00 pm</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="2:00 pm"> <span>2:00 pm</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="3:00 pm"> <span>3:00 pm</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="4:00 pm"> <span>4:00 pm</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="5:00 pm"> <span>5:00 pm</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="6:00 pm"> <span>6:00 pm</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="7:00 pm"> <span>7:00 pm</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="8:00 pm"> <span>8:00 pm</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="9:00 pm"> <span>9:00 pm</span>
                    <input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="10:00pm"> <span>10:00 pm</span>
                      </p>

                <p>
```

Comment: In what way are they not working?

Comment: as I moneted, active should be green

Comment: if I remove the style
 
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
   width: 0;
   position: absolute;
  
}
then default radio buttons appear and  these are working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there. You need to use `label` as oppose to `span` to make sure that when `clicked` the `radio` button are getting `checked` and the `active` **green** CSS is applied to them.

I have fixed up your `HTML` and its all working as expected and created a fully working answer.

Also i have added some `jQuery` code to show (for demo purposes) that when `input` type `radio` button are getting `clicked` (change event) their `correct` value is `showing` in the `console.log` as well.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val()) //just for demo purposes
})
```

```css
.radio-toolbar {
  margin: 10px;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.radio-toolbar label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 30.33%;
  margin: 5px 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.radio-toolbar label:hover {
  background-color: #f79da9;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:focus+label {
  border: 2px dashed #444;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #bfb;
  border-color: #4c4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Time Zone: EST</label><br>
<p class="line-item-property__field radio-toolbar">
  <input required type="radio" id="10" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="10:00 am" checked><label for="10">10:00 am</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="11" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="11:00 am"> <label for="11">10:00 am</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="12" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="12:00 am"><label for="12">12:00 am</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="13" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="1:00 pm"> <label for="13">1:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="14" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="2:00 pm"> <label for="14">2:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="15" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="3:00 pm"> <label for="15">3:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="16" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="4:00 pm"><label for="16">4:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="17" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="5:00 pm"> <label for="17">5:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="18" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="6:00 pm"><label for="18">6:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="19" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="7:00 pm"> <label for="19">7:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="20" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="8:00 pm"> <label for="20">8:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="21" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="9:00 pm"> <label for="21">9:00 am</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="22" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="10:00pm"><label for="22">10:00 am</label>
</p>
```

Comment: Your answer does not meet accessibility requirements

Comment: @Unbywyd What are these requirement ? Please explain - I really want to know these requirements. ?

Comment: Radio buttons must be grouped and have a group label, you should not have an empty label without a link to the input see my answer for details

Comment: @Unbywyd Where is the empty `label` and where are they not grouped ?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/instructions/, see (2.4.6 Headings and Labels) WCAG 2.0 AA and  3.3.2 Labels or Instructions of A lvl, I live in Israel, your HTML does not meet our requirements (this is just an example) we have a requirement WCAG 2.0 AA

Comment: @Unbywyd Read Official [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) - **W3-School** docs have not been updated for almost `100` years. Personal advice do not follow W3 schools.

Comment: W3-School has nothing to do with, I'm talking about the specification and accessibility recommendations on the web pages which in some countries are law. https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/ Welcome to web

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/policies/ check out this document

Comment: @Unbywyd I have no idea what are you saying about all these other countries requirements with web. I wish you best of luck. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You must use label and not span tag, read this article: [Labeling Controls](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/)

```
<input required type="radio" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" id="t1" value="10:00 am" checked><label for="t1">10:00 am</label>
```

---

Also, you should group items with [fieldset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp) replace your label to legend, or use aria tags (role=group, aria-labelledby) more about grouping elements: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA17.html

Example:

```
<fieldset class="line-item-property__field radio-toolbar">
  <legend>Time Zone: EST</legend>
  <input required type="radio" id="a10" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="10:00 am" checked><label for="a10">10:00 am</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a11" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="11:00 am"> <label for="a11">10:00 am</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a12" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="12:00 am"><label for="a12">12:00 am</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a13" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="1:00 pm"> <label for="a13">1:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a14" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="2:00 pm"> <label for="a14">2:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a15" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="3:00 pm"> <label for="a15">3:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a16" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="4:00 pm"><label for="a16">4:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a17" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="5:00 pm"> <label for="a17">5:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a18" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="6:00 pm"><label for="a18">6:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a19" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="7:00 pm"> <label for="a19">7:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a20" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="8:00 pm"> <label for="a20">8:00 pm</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a21" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="9:00 pm"> <label for="a21">9:00 am</label>
  <input required type="radio" id="a22" name="properties[Time Zone: EST]" value="10:00pm"><label for="a22">10:00 am</label>
</fieldset>
```

Pay attention despite the specification HTML5 about [ID](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) as it has many consequences, for example to [create css rules](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/), there is a good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors) and an answer to it

You must understand that any of your html must comply with all required web standards including [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/) accessibility, you can read the accessibility requirements in [your region here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/policies/)